# I cant override method save in model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I would like to add YouTube video on my site, but there is a subtlety. In browser user see URL like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iD8THN4wySA

But for forms on my site I need change URL to this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/iD8THN4wySA

So I've created a model with that code:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(u'Заголовок',max_length =200)
    url = models.CharField(u'URL-адрес',max_length=200)
    width = models.IntegerField(u'Ширина',)
    height = models.IntegerField(u'Высота',)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(u'Время публикации',blank=True, null=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.url = self.url.replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','https://www.youtube.com/embed/')
    super(Video, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

This works in my local testing `manage.py runserver`, but on site the URL doesn't change. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you give an example of url which is not changed? Could be missing `www.` or anything similar.

Comment: http://antonigin.pythonanywhere.com/video/
That's a my site, where i testing code.

Comment: That's what you need?

Comment: If you need URL of video, there is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iD8THN4wySA

Comment: just an idea - did you restart the running wsgi process (I assume it's wsgi) after you updated the code on the server? It needs to be restarted otherwise it will keep running the version from the time you spawned the process initially.

Comment: I found a decision with your help! In pythonaywhere for correct work i must click "Reload [name site]", and i forgot do this. Thank you very much!